# showing wrong year value on click on arrow jquery ui datepicker

Tags: jquery, html

when i click on next arrow its showing me old value which i don't want please help 
here is my jQuery code.

```
$(".common_sideform_datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    beforeShow: function (a) {
        addCustom_class($(this).attr("class"));
    },
    onClose: function (b, a) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var c = "ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all";
            $("#ui-datepicker-div").removeAttr("class").attr("class", c)
        }, 100)
    }
});
```

Comment: What are you clicking on? Can you provide us with your HTML code as well?

Comment: @ZacharyWeixelbaum Thanx for asking i got solution. cheers :)

Comment: Wow, that was a belated response. :) Glad to hear!